# IE9 loads from the cache (when available) instead of the server when xmlhttp-requesting

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm developing locally. and I'm using this code for AJAX:

```
function getChart(num,ld,margin,idr)
{
    idr = typeof(idr) != 'undefined' ? idr : 0;
    $(ld).style.display="inline-block";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            $(ld).style.display="none";
            //to place boxes next to each other
            $("sign_"+num).style.margin=(margin+7)+"px 590px 0 0";
            if(num=="ph"&&$("sign_fx").style.marginTop==$("sign_"+num).style.marginTop&&$("sign_fx").style.marginRight=="590px")
            {
                $("sign_"+num).style.marginRight="605px";
            }
            else if(num=="fx"&&$("sign_ph").style.marginTop==$("sign_"+num).style.marginTop&&$("sign_ph").style.marginRight=="590px")
            {
                $("sign_"+num).style.marginRight="605px";
            }
            else if(num=="fx")
            {
                $("sign_ph").style.marginRight="590px";
            }
            else if(num=="ph")
            {
                $("sign_fx").style.marginRight="590px";
            }
            $("sign_"+num).style.display="block";
            $(num+"_request_ld").style.display="none";
            $(num+"_request_all").style.display="block";
            $(num).style.display="block";
            $(num+"_request").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","barchart.php?idu=<?php echo $id_signed_in;?>&num="+num+"&idr="+idr,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

when the parameters are the same in `getChart` function (meaning `getChart` has been called with same parameters), IE loads from the cache and doesn't bother calling the server even when refreshing the page. on deleting the cache it gets the data from the server. is this because I'm developing locally??

Comment: Have you tried adding a random parameter at the end of your request to barchart.php?

Comment: Yes by assigning them to `getChart` function, it loads them from the server for the first time then when repeating with the same parameters it loads from the catch which means not catching any changes whatsoever in the database. it keeps doing that til I delete the catch then it starts over with same issue.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery or some other lib, you should use the library's Ajax call instead of rolling your own. (You shouldn't be testing for IE6 ActiveObjects, etc.)

Comment: @LarryK Sorry for the misspelling. I'm not using jQuery or any other lib.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember to upvote all useful answers (including answers to other people's questions). Also remember to check (accept) the best answer to your questions which help you solve your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading from the cache is a feature, not a bug. To defeat it, add a cache-busting parameter such as

```
xxx= <new Date().getTime();>  // note, this is meta-code.
```

or just maintain a counter. In any case, identical GET urls (including the parameters) will cause the cached value to be returned. So you need to force the urls to be different.

Or use POST instead of GET.

To put it another way, a basic idea of HTTP GET calls is that they are [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). This means that calling (via GET) http://server.com?a=1&b=2 should **always** return the same answer. Since that should be the case, the response can (and should) be cached.

Since, apparently, you are *not* returning the same answer in each call, your url is *not* idempotent. That is not good from an architectural point of view. While you are first facing a problem with the browser cache, you could also be facing problems with caches at multiple caching points along the path from client to your server. Eg a caching proxy server, etc.

The cache-busting technique I described above (adding a changing parameter to the URL), will work. But better would be to use a POST request.

**Added**

[Caching assumptions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html) in HTTP are complex. I'm simplifying things when I say that HTTP GET urls should be idempotent. Depending on header values and meta-header tags in the HTML body, it is fine to have changing results from a specific GET URL. In the default simple case, the assumption by the browser and intermediate caching points is that the GETs are idempotent.

Since typical simple data response results don't set the caching headers explicitly, the assumption is that the results can be cached. Thus the problem the OP ran into.

Comment: your reply is very informative. thank you so much. using an additional parameter with random value would solve the issue. there is a very slight chance that two `GET` URLs will be identical. however using POST is a lot easy and straight forward. Are any disadvantages of using `POST` in AJAX that I should be aware of.  "Jun1st" in his reply said "it's not recommended" without justifying that.

Comment: Ajax is often done with POST. Main issue is the semantics. If your call is just fetching the most recent data, then a GET, with a cache-busting parameter is the way to go. If your call changes something on the server, and fetches the latest data, then use a POST.

Answer (score 1):

1. using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set `cache:false` instead of making a request from stratch.
2. set `Expire` on your response, which is generated by `barchar.php`
3. using `POST` instead of `GET`, it would solve your issue, but not recommended

Comment: why is't using `POST` recommended?

Comment: POST is supposed to update/add some new data in your server. GET is used to retrieve data from server. that's the definition in HTTP 1.1. the reason POST would work is POST never caches

Comment: had the same problem, I used cache:false which did the trick. this means I did not need to add an extra parameter to the URL just for IE.

Answer (score 0):

A way I've found to work around this is by using a "cache buster" - that is, appending a randomly generated number as a parameter of the request. This parameter shouldn't be named the same as anything that the server expects, so it will just be ignored, but it will trick IE into recognizing it as a new request.

For more information, see [IE Cache and AJAX: Cache Busting Ajax requests](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com/2010/10/cache-busting-ajax-requests-in-ie.html)

Answer (score 0):

expand you xmlhttp.open with some sort of random data e.g. barchart.php?....&_cache=RANDVALUE 
this way the browser will re-request the data each time.

alternatively you have to send data which prevents ie from caching on the server side